# Hot swap strangness going from Windows to Linux

Tags: boot, swap

I have a PC tower with 2 hot swap bays. I exchange HD's depending on what OS i want to use. Lately I was gaming on the Windows side. When I swapped HD to boot up Ubuntu 18.XX or Linux Mint, it looks like it is booting up normally with the purple background and then the screen goes black.

Thinking there is some issue with the OS, I try to install a fresh copy using a USB. I boot to the USB and the same thing happens, booting up normally with the purple background and then the screen goes black. I tried the USB in a laptop, boots fine into the USB like I was going to install or try Ubuntu.

I put the Windows HD in and the PC boots fine. I have :

- PRIME B350-PLUS
- AMD B350 Chipset
- AM4, HDMI
- ATX Motherboard

Any ideas?

Comment: Secure Boot AND Fast Boot disabled in BIOS?  Please check.

Comment: So easy!  You are a beast.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that both Secure Boot and Fast Boot are disabled in the BIOS/firmware setup.